# .exe file randomly deleted

Tags: windows, file-recovery

Hopefully this is a good place to ask this. If it's not, please direct me to the correct place.

---

I recently installed Quartus Prime Lite, a free application like many others, and had been using it for a few weeks.

Today I went to open it as I have always done, by clicking the shortcut on the desktop. But lo and behold, shortcut roke: quartus.exe not found.

So I go and check the folder where the .exe is supposed to be, and it's not there. Strange...

I used Recuva Pro to scan for deleted files in the folder where it's supposed to be, and it discovers a quartus.exe file. However, this file was only 211KB: the Quartus software is several GB. I don't know where this seemingly deleted quartus.exe came from, but in the information section about it, it said:

> Comment: This file is overwritten with
>   "C:\Users\Xtrem\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Extensions\gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom\3.34.0_0\icons"

No idea what this means.

Besides all this, it doesn't seem like anything else has been deleted except for that one particular file. It seems very strange for a particular file to be deleted, among all others.

**Does anyone have any idea how or why this happened?**

Comment: It might just have failed updating itself. But you should check Windows Defender and your antivirus if one of them deleted the exe.

Comment: I was seriously doubting this, but sure enough there is quartus.exe in my AVG Quarantine. Have no clue why it is there, but thank you very much. Any idea why I didn't receive a notification when it was quarantined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the log file and quarantine folder of any antivirus software like Windows Defender, ans also anti malware software.

You can upload the file to an online analysis service like [this one](https://virusscan.jotti.org/). This can give you a clue, why your antimalware/antivirus moved the file.

Comment: This is exactly what the problem was with Avast. The program terminated mid-simulation for me.